# the definite article before numbers

Tags: articles, dates

*The May 1, 2013, edition of the Ames Sentinel arrived in June.*

*The Ames Sentinel—dated May 1, 2013—arrived in June.*

Could you explain to me the presence of the definite article in the first sentence ("The May"). I was thought the rule that the zero article is used when the number in function of adjective comes after the noun, e.g. World War 2 or page 25.

Comment: The noun which *The* determines is *edition*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an ordinal.  "*The fifth* person in line."  The particular day in a series of days.  It is spoken "The May first edition" or "The May tenth edition" or "The May twenty-third edition..."

Comment: The comment of StoneyB is the necessary and sufficient answer to the question.  This answer is nonsense.

Comment: @AST Pace: I believed OP's confusion had arisen from his reading the date as "May one" (as in *WWII*) rather than "May *first*", so I explained that "May 1" represents an ordinal (modifying **edition**). That is not to disagree with StoneyB's comment that "edition" is the noun determined. He sought to clear up the OP's confusion in one way, and I in another.